# Make typing / mypy aware of dynamically resolved superclasses

Tags: python, plugins, typing

In a heavily pluggable / extendable system, which leverages inheritance but doesn't directly use it, is there a way to use typing / tell mypy about *effective* subtyping relationships when these relationships are not provided directly?

Think Ruby-style open classes, but instead of the "extension" concept being a marker class (which in retrospect might have been a better idea but as usual hindsight's 20/20) it's a separate attribute not unlike the old `__metaclass__` of Python 2 e.g.

```py
class A(Pluggable):
    ...

class B(Pluggable):
    __extends__ = A
```

Here if the plugin defining `B` is loaded in the system, the `A` class will be "updated" (really swapped) with a new class extending both `B` and `A`.

So the `B` "class" / extension really should have access to anything `A` defines, but there's no way for mypy (or other typing consumer / analysis) to know that.

Is there a way to tell them of these relationship *without actually having B extends A*? (it would be nice to do that eventually, but currently doing that breaks the entire thing as the bits which manage the class collection and merging get lost and generate invalid MROs).

Comment: typing.Protocol maybe? Difficult to give a specific example without a specific use case, though.

Comment: @AlexWaygood the specific use case is exactly as described, or do you mean a repro case? I'm not sure about Protocol here as it would require a second version of each `Pluggable` with a `Protocol`, that doesn't seem super viable.

Comment: Yes, a second version of  each `Pluggable` was essentially what I had in mind. I agree it's horrible, but I'm not sure there's currently a better alternative. The more dynamic/ extendable your code is, the more mypy will struggle with it, unfortunately. And yes, I meant a reproducible case of something that doesn't type check, that you'd like to type check — sorry for unclear wording. But it sounds like you get my drift anyway.